# Why haven't airlines added safety pads to their carts?

Tags: safety

I chanced upon this question at [5:11](https://youtu.be/SZB4_-tiRt0?t=311) of this YouTube video. Their answer is "no idea".

A cynic would answer profit motive, for it costs money to add safety pads to all these carts and airlines aren't profiting especially in this COVID19 pandemic.

Comment: I think they should build a Safety Cage around each passenger seat.  You say "profit motive" like it's a bad thing.  Profit motive, and success at achieving it, is what keeps everybody employed.

Comment: To avoid this question being closed as opinion-based, you should transform it. I propose "what are pro/cons of safety pads?" . You can also add a picture to illustrate your question see the [help center](/help/dont-ask) for more information.

Comment: Why don't the _passengers_ arrive in bubble wrap to protect themselves from the drink carts and other passengers' luggage and the skinny guy in the middle seat with really pointy elbows who insists on using _both_ armrests? There is danger in the world. It's up to each individual to determine which risks he is willing to take each day. If the risk of getting your elbow bumped by the drink cart is too great for you to fly, then A) drive and have a significantly higher risk of dying in a car crash, or B) don't go. Don't expect the entire planet to be padded for your protection.

Comment: ^ And this is why we don't accept opinion based questions.

Answer (score 11):

Because an inch or two of rubber isn’t going to stop a 300lb cart from breaking your foot if it goes out of control down an aisle. If your elbow is in the wrong position, you could hit it with a 300lb roll of memory foam and cause a compound fracture.

The maker of this video is just looking for things to complain about. Keep your body parts out of the aisle and you’ll be fine.